# How to use libraries function

Tags: 7

I have the libraries module to add some libraries in my drupal site.
Currently I need to use mailjet, I found some modules with some functions to talk with api but I've tested this for multiple hours and can't make this works (functions doesn't works if I don't modify them).

So I want to use the official php library for MailJet, I download it and put it in the sites/all/libraries folder.

In my module I try to call this librarie but doesn't work :

Here a try with libraries_detect :

```
 $name = 'mailjet';
 if (($library = libraries_detect($name)) && !empty($library['installed'])) 
 {
   // The library is installed. Awesome!
   dsm("installed");
 }
 else {
  // Something went wrong. :déçu:
  // This contains a short status code of what went wrong, such as 'not found'.
  $error = $library['error'];
  // This contains a detailed (localized) error message.
  $error_message = $library['error message'];
 }
```

Always pass in the else, and here with libraries_load :

```
if (($library = libraries_load('mailjet')) && !empty($library['loaded'])) {
  // Do something with the library here.
  dsm("Loaded");
} else {
  dsm('not loaded');
}
```

Same, always in the else.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This will only work if whatever module you are using implements hook_library_info. Otherwise Drupal won't know how to locate it.

Comment: But in this hook the libraries module ask for vendor url, download url. Can I use the hook just for specify to drupal that my library is here ? And in the 'files' section of the hook can I just point on the autoloader of the library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install and [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) Module, and put `MailJet` Library to *sites/all/libraries* make sure that your structure like:

```
sites/all/libraries/mailjet/src/Mailjet/Client.php
sites/all/libraries/mailjet/src/Mailjet/Config.php
sites/all/libraries/mailjet/src/Mailjet/Request.php
sites/all/libraries/mailjet/src/Mailjet/Resources.php
sites/all/libraries/mailjet/src/Mailjet/Response.php
```

And then implement `hook_libraries_info` like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_libraries_info().
 */
function myModule_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['mailjet'] = array(
    'name'              => 'mailjet',
    'vendor url'        => 'https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php',
    'download url'      => 'https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/archive/master.zip',
     // version arguments it's important, mailjet libary version can be found in Config.php file in line 19.
    'version arguments' => array(
      'file'    => 'src/Mailjet/Config.php',
      'pattern' => '/v+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/',
      'lines'   => 19,
    ),
    'files'             => array(
      'php' => array(
        'src/Mailjet/Client.php',
        'src/Mailjet/Config.php',
        'src/Mailjet/Request.php',
        'src/Mailjet/Resources.php',
        'src/Mailjet/Response.php',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Now you can load your library like

```
$library = libraries_load('mailjet');
  if ($library['loaded']) {
    dsm("Loaded");
  }
  else {
    dsm('not loaded');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just add the autoload.php in php files (I use the no composer version) and it works